# $\sigma$-algebra generated by weak topology in Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

In general, if we have $H$ Hilbert space, and equipped with the weak topology, say $\tau^\ast$, is $\sigma(\tau^*)=\mathcal{B}$?, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the usual Borel $\sigma$-algebra

I suspect it is.

By definition, $\tau^*$ is the minimum topology for which elements of $H^\prime(=H)$ are continuous. Then, $\sigma(\tau^*)\subseteq\mathcal{B}$.

But for the other inclusion, do you have any hint?

Comment: Can you explain why $\sigma(\tau^*)\subseteq\mathcal{B}$? Can we assert that $\sigma(\tau^*)$ is the minimal $\sigma$-algebra such that all elements of $H'$ are measurable?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:** If $H$ is separable:

Let $(e_i)$ be an orthonormal basis for $H$. 
Then for $x\in H$ and $N<\infty$ the function 
$y\mapsto \sum_{i=1}^N\langle y-x,e_i\rangle^2$ is weakly continuous, 
and so $\sigma(\tau^*)$-measurable. 
Also the limit $y\mapsto\|y-x\|^2=\lim_N \sum_{i=1}^N\langle y-x,e_i\rangle^2$ is $\sigma(\tau^*)$-measurable. 
Thus every open ball $B(x,\varepsilon)=\{y\in H: \|y-x\|<\varepsilon\}\in \sigma(\tau^*)$.

Can you take it from here?

---

**Hint 2:** If $H$ is not separable.

Assume that $\{0\}\in \sigma(\tau^*)$ and derive a contradiction.

Comment: Is not a strong hypothesis that $\{e_i\}$ is enumerable?

Comment: @sinbadh Sorry, my mistake. I thought that you had assumed that $H$ is separable. I doubt if the result is true otherwise.

Comment: A bit late to the party here, but I'm fairly confident the result is still true even without separability. For one thing, since the weak topology of a Banach space is Hausdorff, $\{0\}$ is closed, hence $\{0\} \in \sigma(\tau^*)$ so I don't see how one would derive a contradiction from a true statement. The way to show it (in both the separable and non separable cases) is to note that convex sets are closed iff they are weakly closed, hence all closed balls are in $\sigma(\tau^*)$, thus one can easily show that so are open balls, hence all of $\sigma(\tau)$.

Comment: @PhysicalMathematics The open balls lie in $\sigma(\tau^*)$, but does every open set if the space is not separable?